# Android If-Else-statement stops after else

Tags: android, if-statement, asynchronous

So I have below Android code that works. But only until the point pointed out below in the code. The HTTPPost Gets back a JSON string from a webserver. In the postExecute I check the returned JSONObject on the key value "success". If it is 1 then do something. Else do something else. However the "do something else" is not working. Not sure why not. App does not crash but simply goes back to the screen.

Also any tips for better code on below is also appreciated as I am new to this.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Registreren extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPass;
    TextView textError;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registreren);
        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        inputPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_pass);
        textError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
    }

    public void registreer (View v) {
        String serverURL = "http://www.somesite.com";
        new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
    }

    public void openLogin (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Registreren.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Een moment geduld aub...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String naam = inputName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass = inputPass.getText().toString();
            JSONObject finalResult = null;
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            //Set the connection timeout and socket timeout parameters (ms)
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters,5000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.com");
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", naam));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity responseEntity =response.getEntity();
                if (responseEntity != null){
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(responseEntity.getContent(),"UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (String line ; (line = reader.readLine()) !=null;) {
                        builder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
                    try{
                        finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data error.Probeer het later nog eens", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geen response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return finalResult;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            Integer succes;
            String naam;
            String pass;
            String email;
            try {
                succes = result.getInt("succes");
                naam   = result.getString("username");
                pass   = result.getString("pass");
                email  = result.getString("email");
                if(succes==1){
                    SharedPreferences userDetails =getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                    edit.clear();
                    edit.putString("username", naam);
                    edit.putString("password", pass);
                    edit.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Overzicht.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                else  {//in debug i can come until this line
                    if(naam.equals("user_bestaat")){//this line and below is ignored
                        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);
                        t.setText("Gebruikersnaam bestaat al");
                    }
                    if(email == "email_bestaat"){
                        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);
                        t.setText("Email is al geregistreerd");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data error.Probeer het later nog eens", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

            Dialog.dismiss();
            //SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
           // System.out.println("value of the userdertails ==========>"+ userDetails);
            //String Uname="";
            //String pass= "";

           // Uname = userDetails.getString("username", "");
            //pass = userDetails.getString("password", "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_overzicht, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of naam and email? You're checking to see if they equal "user_bestaat" and "email_bestaat", but those if statements would not execute if they don't equal that.

Comment: `if(email == "email_bestaat")` should be `if(email.equals("email_bestaat"))` , just like the `if` statement above it.

Comment: @Willis I have used both to see if one of them triggers it. Have changed around also but it just go's out of the code after the else (tried it with debugging)

Comment: @Christf Checked the values and they actualy are the same as the if statements

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the else and step into? Try that, and you'll be able to step through exactly what the app is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing with `==` means compare by reference which is not the case here. You want to compare the value of two strings.

Change to this

```
if(email.equals("email_bestaat")){
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);
    t.setText("Email is al geregistreerd");
}
```

Comment: Thought i had tryed with both .equals() butn guess only tried both with == Thanks for your help people

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to accept it as your answer then. :D